# Alinha o sistema de postagem

Tags: php, html5

```
<?php
    require_once 'Postagem/system/config.php';
    require_once 'Postagem/system/database.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<?php include 'include/head.php'; ?>
<?php include 'include/nav.php'; ?>


<div class="card mb-3">
  <img class="card-img-top" src="img/cap.png" alt="Card image cap">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h4 class="card-title"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">Forex</span></h4>
    <p class="card-text"><span style="margin-left: 15px;">O maior site de conteudo forex da America Latina.</p>
    <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"></span></small></p>
  </div>
</div>

<style type="text/css">
.inserirLayout{
    height:auto;
    width: auto;
}

.inserirLayout li{
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 0 15px 0;
    display: block;
    height:40px;
}
</style>

<!--Exibindo alguns dados-->


<main>

    <?php
        $posts = DBRead('posts', "WHERE status = 1 ORDER BY data DESC");

        if (!$posts)
            echo '<h2>Nenhuma postagem encontrada!</h2>';
        else
            foreach ($posts as $post): 
    ?>


<ul class="inserirLayout">
    <li>
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;  ">

        <img class="card-img-top" src="Postagem/painel/uploads/<?php echo $post['image_text']; ?>" alt="Card image cap" height="318px" width="180px">

            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">
                    <a href="Postagem/exibe.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $post['titulo']; ?>">
                        <?php echo $post['titulo']; ?></h4>

                    </a>    
                            <p class="card-text">
                                <?php
                                    $str = strip_tags($post['conteudo']);
                                    $len = strlen($str);
                                    $max = 500;

                                    if ($len <= $max)
                                        echo $str;
                                    else
                                        echo substr($str, 0, $max) . '...';

                                ?>
                            </p>

                            <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted"><?php echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($post['data'])) ?>
                                , Visitas <b><?php echo $post['visitas']; ?></b>,
                                por <b><?php echo $post['autor']; ?></b>
                            </small>
                            </p>



                        <a href="Postagem/exibe.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>" title="<?php echo $post['titulo']; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Leia a Materia</a>
            </div>

    </div>


    </li>
</ul>

    <?php endforeach; ?>




</main> 

</html>
```

quero que ele imprima a postagem em linha vertical de 3 
toda vez q tiver **3 postagem em uma linha vertical**
ele pule de linha

preciso dessa ajuda

Comment: Olá Vitor! Vc é de Portugal?

Comment: OlA, sou do Brasil

Comment: Sua pergunta ficou confusa. Não seria "linha horizontal" em vez de "linha vertical"?

Comment: Porque "linha" geralmente quer dizer "horizontal", enquanto que "vertical" tem mais a ver com "coluna".

Comment: horizontal no caso

Comment: Entendi. A resposta abaixo resolve?

Comment: Ainda não, ele esta pulando,  e não ta deixando completa nem 3 ,

Comment: Então é porque 3 não cabe na tela na mesma linha.

Comment: http://farolandia.atspace.cc/png/

Comment: pra ver se fica facil

Comment: A ideia é essa da resposta do @Cayo Henrique Rodrigues... Coloque um `<br clear="all" />` em vez de `<br />`, e no CSS retire o `height:40px;`, que aliás, não sei pra que q serve.

Comment: Tem uma tag `<h4>` com um `<a>` dentro e vc colou um `</h4>`dentro do `<a>`... isso tah errado tb

Comment: Seu HTML ficaria mais ou menos assim: https://jsfiddle.net/m3w6bypm/

Comment: Valeu, funcionou

Comment: Que bom. Sucesso!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, 
no seu foreach, voce pode pegar o index e dividi-lo por 3, caso a divisão tenha resto 0, você adiciona um 
Assim

```
<?php
    foreach ($posts as $index => $post): 
        if($index % 3 == 0) {
?>
           <br />
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: não foi,  ele ta pulando linha,

Comment: porem , e nessa base a logica,

Comment: 3 postagem em uma linha ai ele automaticamente pula de linha

Comment: ai mais 3, porai vai

Comment: Qual o comportamento exato que você quer? Não era para pular de linha a cada 3 itens?

Comment: http://farolandia.atspace.cc/png/

Comment: pra ver se fica meio facil

Comment: como havia explicado, tipo, a cada 3 postagens horizontas, ele pula a linha, e coloca mais 3 postagens,

Comment: funcionou junto com a outra

Comment: funcionou sim,valeu o problema era o meu css